# Where do I find the Create App button?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, blogs

I am trying to create an app for facebook to link to my Wordpress blog. Every time I click on developers.facebook.com/apps I get taken to my FB page. I have already upgraded my FB to a developer account. The FB page is for a business and is NOT a personal page. I have spent hours reading on line and getting absolutely no where trying to create the app. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a case of https://developers.facebook.com/apps and if you've not allowed it yet the permissions box should come up.  You should also have access to the developer app from your dashboard.  Have you "allowed" the app yet?

Comment: I haven't created the app yet. I have the Facebook plugin activated on Wordpress, but I can't put in the App ID and App secret, because I can't get to where I need to create the app.